# Authenticate as first pass param to BLE device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I need to authenticate to BLE device that requires a key >SBIK12345< first all. I can't write any characteristic and service without the key before.

Some idea?

This is my connect method (from this repo [BluLeGatt from Anlif](https://github.com/anlif/android-BluetoothLeGatt))

```
public boolean connect(final String address)
{
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null)
    {
        System.out.println(TAG+"BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }
    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null)
    {
        System.out.println(TAG+"Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null)
    {
        System.out.println(TAG+"Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    try
    {
        device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_BLE_080));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("exc createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
    System.out.println(TAG+" Trying to create a new connection.");

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic1 = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_BLE_080),BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    characteristic1.setValue(">SBIK1234<");

    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic1);

    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}
```

And the static var is

```
public static String UUID_BLE_080 = "00000000-dc70-0080-dc70-a07ba85ee4d6";
```

Comment: You need to wait for the device to connect and until services have been discovered, i.e. wait for onServicesDiscovered() until you write your characteristic.

Comment: Hi, sure I do that, but the device is not aceppting write after connect without key pass, is a syrus ble device, thanks